# Sonarlint false positive NullPointer warning (S2259) when using ResponseEntity

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, sonarqube, nullable, sonarlint

For general restTemplate operation,as :

```
ResponseEntity<ResponseVO> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(url, entity, ResponseVO.class);
if (response.getBody() != null) {
    String url = response.getBody().getUrl();
```

I'm getting wrong sonar warning when reusing the `ResponseEntity`:

```
A "NullPointerException" could be thrown; "getBody()" can return null. sonarlint(java:S2259)
```

Also if I refactor and introduce a variable no warning appears:

```
ResponseVO body = response.getBody();
if (body != null) {
    String url = body.getUrl();
```

I don't need to add `response != null`, if added there's a different (ok) warning:

```
Remove this expression which always evaluates to "true" [+3 locations]sonarlint(java:S2589)
```

Is it SonarLint bug? why it warns about NullPointerException?

I suspect it's related to HttpEntity `@Nullable` definition

```
@Nullable
public T getBody() {
```

I didn't find similar issue in [jira.sonarsource](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1889?filter=-4&jql=text%20%7E%20%22java%3AS2259%22%20order%20by%20created%20DESC)

Comment: Well, at least, two subsequent calls to `getBody()` *could* return different results if the resulting `ResponseVO` is mutable and some other thread changes its value. That's not possible if you store it in a local variable first. However, I do not know whether this is the reason why SonarLint issues a warning here.

Comment: @MCEmperor I don't think it's related for HttpEntity's `private final T body`

Comment: Another way this can trigger: `MyClass debug = null; if (debug?.Buffer?.Length > 0) return debug.Buffer[0];` -- assuming MyClass has a byte[] Buffer property.

Comment: I also logged an issue: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-dotnet/issues/6149

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raised a [false-positive](https://community.sonarsource.com/t/sonarlint-wrong-nullpointerexception-warning-s2259-when-reusing-responseentity/55510) in Sonar community and answered by @DamienUrruty

> indeed it looks like a false-positive. That said it might make the rule more complex to support this case